# How to log out a session then log another one?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

What I'm trying to achive is that if user 1 is logged in and I want to log in the same user 1 from another device. It will log out the first user 1 and the second user 1 will stay logged in.

I'm currently have only flag "active" in DB which determinate if user is logged in. That means if user will log in the flag is set up for 1 and if he's logged out it's set back to 0.

When the same user want to log in it will run the if statement checking if the active state is set up for 1 if so display error that the user is logged in if it's 0 log him inside the app.

Thanks for any advices :)

Answer (score 1):

Configure your app to use the [database session driver](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#driver-prerequisites). After second user is logged in - remove all (other) sessions by user_id.

There is few ways to remove other sessions. I think that `session_id()` or similar framework method will return real id from session table.  When second user is authenticated, `session_id()` should return current session id which shouldn't be removed.

Comment: @codeHysteria127 Please, let me know how the solution worked for you :)

Comment: I used something from your answer like usage for session_id but instead of configuring session driver a created middleware. But thanks anyway